# Connected subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\Bbb{C}^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis, connectedness

During my complex analysis course. My instructor gave me the definition a set in Complex plane is said to be connected if any points of the set can be joined by polygon lines that should be contained in the set.

I liked this definition very much. As it was helping a lot to check which sets are connected and which are not.

I want to know is this definition also valid for real plane
$\mathbb{R}^2$.

Because today when I was doing a question to check whether a unit circle centered at origin is connected or not.
I immediately said it is not connected as we cannot draw polygon lines between any two distinct points lying on the unit circle such that the polygon line belongs to the set.
But the correct answer was connected.

Please help me how is it possible. And I would also like to know is $|z|=1$ also connected (I am not taking the part inside circle) just the boundary.

Please help me clear my doubt.

Comment: The boundary, the unit circle,  is connected. Given two points in the unit circle, they can be connected with a path that is also contained in the set. Connectedness, in this case a strong type of connectedness called Path connectedness, exists if any two points in the set can be joined by a path that is connected in the set. It doesn't necessarily have to be polygonal.

Comment: You mean to say path connected implies connected ?

Comment: Correct. Every path connected space must be connected. The converse isn't always true.

Comment: Great. Thank you for your help.

Comment: May I extend the question a bit..is a unit circle centered at origin compact ? If yes then how? I think it is compact as must have a finite subcover . Am I correct?

Comment: Yes it is compact. In Euclidean space, a subset is compact iff it is closed and bounded. Or you can see this directly as you say by finding a finite subcover of an arbitrary cover.

Comment: Ask the instructor why the unit circle is not connected.  Let us know what he says.

Comment: The usual def'n of a connected set $S$ is that whenever $A,B$ are open sets with $A\cup B\supset S$ and $A\cap B\cap S=\emptyset$ then  one of $A\cap S,\; B\cap S$ is empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Topologically there is no difference between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

The statement of your instructor is true for **open** connected subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ (so called open domains), not for all subsets.

The unit circle ( $\{z :|z|=1 \}$) is connected (we can find continuous paths between any two points, e.g. or we can write it as a continuous image of the connected space $\mathbb{R}$ using $t \to e^{it}$ etc.).